# Is there a tablet with the same bezels and size as iPad Pro 11"?

Tags: android, tablet

So, basically, I'm looking for any kind of Android tablet with tiny bezels and the size of the iPad Pro 11". If the aspect ratio is somewhere from 4:3 to a 4.3:3, is a super plus (actual aspect ratio for that mentioned iPad).

I want to use it for:

1. Reading
2. Media consumption
3. Web surfing
4. And all the light stuff that tablets are for

I don't want to pay those $800+, simply because I don't need all the power of that iPad. I don't need a pencil, nor any other fancy things. Just tiny bezels, that aspect ratio (if possible), and Android.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [Samsung Galaxy Tab S4 ($649)](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/tablets/galaxy-tab-s/s/_/n-10+11+hv1rq+zq2js/)? It has a 10.5 inch screen, 64GB of storage, the bezels aren’t as thin.